# Getting author of last post

Tags: python, django, django-models

So I have two models: Thread, ForumPost

With a many-to-one relationship (each Thread can have many ForumPosts).

I would like to display the author of the last post made into that thread.

I'm currently doing:

```
threads = Thread.objects.annotate(replies=Count('forumpost'), lastpost=Max('forumpost'))
```

And I can access it in my view by doing:

```
<td>{{thread.lastpost}}</td>
```

This works fine - but it doesn't do what I want - this only displays the last post ID (which is logical, because I'm displaying the post), not the author. So when I try to do:

```
<td>{{thread.lastpost.author}}</td>
```

It won't display the author (it's blank), although I have

```
author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

In my ForumPost model. So how do I go on about displaying the author, not the ID?

Models:

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class ForumPost(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Comment: Can you share (relevant parts) of your models?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Added to post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a [subquery expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions).

```
newest = ForumPost.objects.filter(post=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-pk')
threads = Thread.objects.annotate(last_post_author=Subquery(newest.values('author')[:1]))
```

Now each thread has a `last_post_author` attribute with the value of the author of the last post.

Note, you should really have a more specific field to order on - pk will usually be chronological, but it's not guaranteed. Add a `created_at` field with auto_now_add and order by that in the subquery.